# ORDER BY COUNT EN SUBCONSULTAS SQL

Tags: mysql, subconsultas, count, orderby

En mis pequeñas prácticas con SQL me he topado con algo inusual. En teoría, las subconsultas tienen ciertas restricciones, como por ejemplo, no incluir varias columnas, no poder poner ORDER BY, etc.
Sin embargo, me he encontrado con una subconsulta en la que aparece un ORDER BY COUNT(). Y no tengo idea de cómo funciona!!! No entiendo los resultados que me arroja.
Alguien me podría explicar la lógica?

La siguiente es mi tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente código en MySQL:

```
SELECT submission_date,
(
    SELECT hacker_id
    FROM practicas.Submissions S2
    WHERE S2.submission_date = S1.submission_date
    GROUP BY hacker_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(submission_id) DESC, hacker_id ASC
    LIMIT 1
) AS TMP
```

FROM practicas.Submissions S1
GROUP BY submission_date

me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La subconsulta que aparece en este código en MySQL tiene como objetivo encontrar el hacker con el mayor número de envíos para cada fecha de envío en la tabla practicas.Submissions. La subconsulta se realiza para cada fecha de envío en la tabla practicas.Submissions, y el resultado se devuelve como una columna adicional en la consulta principal. La subconsulta realiza los siguientes pasos: 1. Utiliza la cláusula WHERE para filtrar las filas de la tabla practicas.Submissions y quedarse solo con las filas que tienen la misma fecha de envío que la fila actual en la consulta principal. 2. Utiliza l

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Cristian Zuñiga.

Comment: Entiendo el razonamiento que hacés. Lo razono de la misma manera que vos. Pero si nuestra lógica fuera cierta, el primer registro que debería mostrarse en la columna hacker_id sería el 36396. Fijate que en fecha 2016-03-01 todos los hackers tienen un envío. El conteo para ese grupo en específico es 1. Y sin embargo muestra el valor 20703.

Comment: Si editas tu publicación y pones los datos en otra forma que no sea imagen podría ayudarte mejor

Comment: Disculpas, pero soy nuevo y no sé cómo publicarlo de otra manera.
De todas maneras, muy agradecido por tomarte un tiempo en intentar ayudarme.

Comment: Puedes ver cómo hacerlo [aquí] (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) a la izquierda de mi respuesta hay unas flechas. Y para crear una nueva pregunta, haz lo mismo que para esta, presiona el botón "Formular una pregunta" que está arriba a la derecha

Comment: Revisando tu primer respuesta @Cristian Zuñiga, la parte en la que explicás el orden descendente creo que me hizo ver el problema de otra manera.
Los hackers que tienen 2 envíos y los hackers que están solos (tengan uno o diez envíos), se muestran en la salida. Eso está super claro.

Comment: Gracias, si te sirvió, recuerda marcar la pregunta como resuelta. Que tengas buen día!

Comment: Ahora bien, mi problema era que no entendía aquellos casos en los que todos los hackers habían hecho un solo envío ese día. No entendía el criterio de selección del hacker. Pero ahora creo saber por qué (en teoría)
Supongo que el DESC en un ORDER BY COUNT() tiene que ver con que primero ordena por el menor envío. Y recién después de eso, busca el menor valor de hacker (por tener un orden ASC)

Comment: Igualmente para vos.